# How to install federated authenticators in wso2 API manager 2.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to install following feature in wso2 API manager  2.0.

http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/05/13/federated-authenticators-in-wso2-api-manager-wso2apim/

but I am getting error in API manager's console while installations.

It seems the above  package is not compatible for 2.0 version.

Please suggest me the exact version of 'Application Authenticator' feature which is compatible with  wso2 AM version  2.0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: WSO2 API Manager 2.0 is based on Carbon 4.4.7 (Wilkes). Hence you need to use P2 repository for Carbon 4.4.x i.e. http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/. Can you verify whether you have added the correct repository?

Comment: I tried with windows 10 ,Is there any chance to get error ?

Comment: No. What is the feature repository URL you have added? http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/turing/ or http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/ (Step 2 in the above blog post you have given)?

Comment: tried with both links ,but getting error as follows

Comment: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: OpenID Connect Application Authenticator Server Feature 5.0.7 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.oidc.server.feature.group 5.0.7) Software currently installed: Identity Application Management Server Feature 5.2.0

Comment: (org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.server.feature.group 5.2.0) Only one of the following can be installed at once: Identity Application Management Server Feature 5.0.7 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.server.feature.jar 5.0.7) Identity Application Management Server Feature 5.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.server.feature.jar 5.2.0) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: OpenID Connect Application Authenticator Server Feature 5.0.7

Comment: (org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.oidc.server.feature.group 5.0.7) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.server.feature.group [5.0.7,5.1.0) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Identity Application Management Server Feature 5.0.7 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.server.feature.group 5.0.7) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.server.feature.jar [5.0.7] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Identity Application

Comment: Management Server Feature 5.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.server.feature.group 5.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.server.feature.jar [5.2.0]

Comment: Windows version wont cause this error. Can I know what's your use case here?.

Comment: I need to connect api manager 2.0 with openam

Comment: please refer this URL  http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/04/28/federated-authentication-for-granting-oauth2-access-token-with-wso2-api-manager-apim/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the p2 repos are still not updated with the latest Authenticator versions based on Identity Application Management Server Feature 5.2.0 or above. This will be updated soon with the next release.

However you can use WSO2 IS for this use case. You can configure SSO for APIM with IS using [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+SAML2) . Then you can federate IS for OpenAM with [this link](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/05/12/federated-authentication-integration-openam-with-wso2is-using-openid-connect/) . With that you can connect APIM with openAM.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does not meet my requirment , Not possible to add one more server for this perticular use case.thank you for response